# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing compiled Typescript files to each other

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using some compiled Typescript, accessed using `<script src="../my-project/index.js"></script>` in index.html.
`index.js` then imports stuff from other compiled Typescript files, using `import X from "./X";` in the typescript, which is kept exactly the same in the compiled `.js` files.
My tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "./"
  },
  "files": [
    "./src/index.ts",
    "./src/file1.ts",
    "./src/file2.ts",
    "./src/file3.ts",
  ]
}
```

I want to use the compiled JS files as normal JS, but for some reason it won't let me. I've done a little research into modules, but I don't understand why this is a module, if that's the problem.

Comment: add in your tag `type="module"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Joseph, thats fixed it.

I ran into another problem importing the contents of the module script into another script, so I added the `type="module"` to all of the scripts. Not sure if that is a good solution, but it seems to work.